# Is anyway to add a new tag for all the installation available in Notification Hub?

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

We need to add a new tag for all the installations available in notification hub,currently we are fetching all the installation ID's stored in our backend and checking each installation for whether the new tag is there in notification hub or not. if the new tag is not available for that user then we are adding the new tag to that installation.is any other way we can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPS,

Your question is valid and as of today there is no other way to achieve what you are doing.

So yes you have to get all your installations one by one and update the installation tags with the one you want to add.